# Fail to uninstall anaconda with error of "CalledPRocessError"

Tags: python, anaconda

When I uninstalled anaconda using control panel, it came out a window which reminded me there is an error named `CalledProcessError`. The traceback is as following:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Wisse\anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py", line 345, in <module> main()
 win_del(sys.argv[2].strip())
File "C:\Users\Wisse\anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py", line 282, in win_del
 out = check_output('DEL/F/Q/S*.*>NUL', shell=True, stderr=STDOUT, cwd=dirname)
File "C:\Users\Wisse\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
 return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "C:\Users\Wisse]anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
 raise CalledProcessError(retcide, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'DEL/F/Q/S*.*>NUL' returned non_zero exit status1.
```

But it seems that anaconda can be uninstalled sucessfully. However, when I try to uninstall it again, the same error will be threw out also. I want to know how to handle this error to avoid it.
[The origin error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBTkb.png)

Comment: I have the same error. Reported here https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11369. Maybe related to https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-prettier/issues/18